# lack of robustness to EOF and newline character in my program

Tags: c, linked-list

I have the following **structures**, to implement a `text editor` in **terminal** using **C**-

```
typedef struct word
{
    char w[15];
    struct word *next, *prev;
}WORD;
```

and

```
typedef struct text
{
    WORD *r;
    int no_of_words;
}TEXT;
```

The following is a **function,** that helps me store all words typed -

```
void type()
{
    TEXT t;
    init(&t);
    char a[10] ="\0",b='\0';
    int i = 2;
    while(b != EOF)
    {   
        while(b!=' '&& b != EOF)
        {
            b = getch();
            if(b!=EOF)
            {
                a[i-2] = b;
                a[i-1] = '\0';
            } 
            i++;
        }
        append(&t,a);
        i=2;
    }
}
```

The problem I face here is that, if I press the `Enter` key or if I invoke the `EOF` character using `ctrl+D,` the computer begins to hang.

The append part was tested on *numbers* and seemed to work *perfectly well*. Even while storing *strings*, it *works very well* as long as `Enter` or `ctrl+D` is **not** pressed.

Can anyone tell me how to rectify this problem?

Comment: If you are so sure about `append`, I am betting the problem is right there. And you never check `i` is out of bounds of `a`. Surely it has nothing to do with `EOF`.

Comment: But I did test it many times. The entire code seems to work perfectly until it encounters newline or EOF. Before that, no matter how many alphabets, I key in it never hangs.

Comment: I am not going to argue about it. The code presented has to comply with the [mcve] requirement.

Comment: You will never detect EOF.  getch() returns an int, and you are truncating it to a char before your EOF check.  Mega-dupe.

Comment: Why do you start `i` at 2? It would be easier and more logical to start it at 0 as then it represents the size of the string in `a`.

Comment: No reason for `i++` outside the `if(b!=EOF)`.  Move it inside.

Comment: `char b=0;` --> `int b=0;`

Comment: @MartinJames With _signed_ `char`, `b!=EOF` _may_ work to detect EOF.  Still better to use `int b;`.

Comment: Better to post the input used that just describe the input.

Comment: Thx a lot for helping me people. I made 2 changes- 1st, I changed b to integer type. Then, I chaged b =getchar() to scanf("%d",&b). It worked. This made it work.